# Css transition not affecting other elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation, transition

Hi everybody I have a school project where I am trying to animate some objects and I got the css transitions to work but I don't want the other elements to be affected by the transition. I have looked at other examples that talk about using css positioning to overcome this problem but when I adding positioning to my example the images start twitching and the other the html elements go all over the place. I am attaching my jsbin. I am using angularjs to loop through an api that I am using, I don't know if that is affecting it somehow?

http://jsbin.com/opEhAVi/1/edit

Comment: it is not js or css causing the issue, it is not absolutely or fixed positioning, which causes it to affect the page layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that is animated needs to be absolutely positioned not to affect the other elements when it for example changes size.

A way to handle it is to make a list of relatively positioned elements. These elements will just be containers to achieve the layout you desire. Each element then contains an absolutely positioned element. This is the content, the element to be animated. As it is absolutely positioned it will not affect the other elements.

I made some quick changes to your example that will hopefully guide you further:

http://jsbin.com/ogAvAZUm/2/edit